# Python cv2 drawing and coordinates are acting unexpectedly

Tags: python, opencv, ip-camera

Using the code

```
import cv2

url = '' # Video HTML
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)

WIN_NAME = 'Mobile Capture'

while 1:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        cv2.circle(frame, (frame.shape[0] // 2, frame.shape[1] // 2), 10, (0, 0, 0), 5)
        cv2.imshow(WIN_NAME, frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

with the Android app IP Webcam, I expected to simply draw a circle in the center of the screen. However, the circle appears lower and to the left of the center of the displayed window.

I've searched online and it doesn't seem that people are having this issue. Any suggestions as to why this issue is occurring?

Comment: shape[0] is height and shape[1] is width. So you want to use shape[1],shape[0] for coordinates in circle().

Comment: Thanks! I guess my cv2 knowledge is not the greatest.